# R: How to get piecewise coefficients of an interpolation spline for analytical integration?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, integral, polynomials

**Motivation**

I am numerically evaluating a deeply-nested multiple integral. At each nesting level I get a vector of integrals at the level below, which are multiplied by a vector of density functions to give the vector of integrands `y` at this level. The `x` values are unevenly spaced.

The integrand is curved and a trapezoidal integration is not sufficiently accurate, so I want to do an integration that allows for curvature. Simpson's Rule is not applicable because the abscissae are not evenly spaced. So I propose to do a cubic spline interpolation and then calculate the integral of the spline function by analytically calculating the integral of the cubic in each segment.

**Question**

I have been looking at functions like `spline` and `splinefun` as well as those in the `splines2` package. But I cannot find anything that tells me the coefficients of the series of cubic polynomials - one per segment between knots.

I would be grateful if somebody could point me to a function that does the spline interpolation and makes available the array of cubic coefficients.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a great opportunity to extend my new answer here: [How to save and load spline interpolation functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51540182/4891738) With that piecewise parametrization, it is easy to compute piecewise integral.

[image]

Here is a (vectorized) function for its computation:

```
## a function for integration on a piece
piecewise_int <- function (hi, yi, bi, ci, di) {
  yi * hi + bi * hi ^ 2 / 2 + ci * hi ^ 3 / 3 + di * hi ^ 4 / 4
  }
```

In the following, I will take the small example in that thread, showing how to integrate the spline.

```
## the small example in the linked thread
set.seed(0)
xk <- c(0, 1, 2)
yk <- round(runif(3), 2)
f <- splinefun(xk, yk, "natural")  ## natural cubic spline
construction_info <- environment(f)$z

## information for integration
int_info <- with(construction_info,
                 list(h = diff(x), y = y[-n], b = b[-n], c = c[-n], d = d[-n])
                 )

## cubic spline integration on all pieces
integral <- sum(do.call(piecewise_int, int_info))
#[1] 0.81375
```

We can also perform a numerical integration to verify this result.

```
integrate(f, 0, 2)
#0.81375 with absolute error < 9e-15
```