# get x-value given y-value: general root finding for linear / non-linear interpolation function

Tags: r, regression, interpolation, spline

I am interested in a general root finding problem for an interpolation function.

Suppose I have the following `(x, y)` data:

```
set.seed(0)
x <- 1:10 + runif(10, -0.1, 0.1)
y <- rnorm(10, 3, 1)
```

as well as a linear interpolation and a cubic spline interpolation:

```
f1 <- approxfun(x, y)
f3 <- splinefun(x, y, method = "fmm")
```

How can I find `x`-values where these interpolation functions cross a horizontal line `y = y0`? The following is a graphical illustration with `y0 = 2.85`.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
curve(f1, from = x[1], to = x[10]); abline(h = 2.85, lty = 2)
curve(f3, from = x[1], to = x[10]); abline(h = 2.85, lty = 2)
```

[image]

I am aware of a few previous threads on this topic, like

- [predict x values from simple fitting and annoting it in the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37455512/4891738)
- [Predict X value from Y value with a fitted model](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43322568/4891738)

It is suggested that we simply reverse `x` and `y`, do an interpolation for `(y, x)` and compute the interpolated value at `y = y0`.

However, this is a bogus idea. Let `y = f(x)` be an interpolation function for `(x, y)`, this idea is only valid when `f(x)` is a monotonic function of `x` so that `f` is invertible. Otherwise `x` is not a function of `y` and interpolating `(y, x)` makes no sense.

Taking the linear interpolation with my example data, this fake idea gives

```
fake_root <- approx(y, x, 2.85)[[2]]
# [1] 6.565559
```

First of all, the number of roots is incorrect. We see two roots from the figure (on the left), but the code only returns one. Secondly, it is not a correct root, as

```
f1(fake_root)
#[1] 2.906103
```

is not 2.85.

I have made my first attempt on this general problem at [How to estimate x value from y value input after approxfun() in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52650467/4891738). The solution turns out stable for linear interpolation, but not necessarily stable for non-linear interpolation. I am now looking for a stable solution, specially for a cubic interpolation spline.

---

#### How can a solution be useful in practice?

Sometimes after a **univariate** linear regression `y ~ x` or a **univariate** non-linear regression `y ~ f(x)` we want to backsolve `x` for a target `y`. This Q & A is an example and has attracted many answers: [Solve best fit polynomial and plot drop-down lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41687406/4891738), but none is truly adaptive or easy to use in practice.

- The accepted answer using `polyroot` only works for a simple polynomial regression;
- Answers using quadratic formula for an analytical solution only works for a quadratic polynomial;
- My answer using `predict` and `uniroot` works in general, but is not convenient, as in practice using `uniroot` needs interaction with users (see [Uniroot solution in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38961221/4891738) for more on `uniroot`).

It would be really good if there is an adaptive and easy-to-use solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, let me copy in the stable solution for linear interpolation proposed in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52650890/4891738).

```
## given (x, y) data, find x where the linear interpolation crosses y = y0
## the default value y0 = 0 implies root finding
## since linear interpolation is just a linear spline interpolation
## the function is named RootSpline1
RootSpline1 <- function (x, y, y0 = 0, verbose = TRUE) {
  if (is.unsorted(x)) {
     ind <- order(x)
     x <- x[ind]; y <- y[ind]
     }
  z <- y - y0
  ## which piecewise linear segment crosses zero?
  k <- which(z[-1] * z[-length(z)] <= 0)
  ## analytical root finding
  xr <- x[k] - z[k] * (x[k + 1] - x[k]) / (z[k + 1] - z[k])
  ## make a plot?
  if (verbose) {
    plot(x, y, "l"); abline(h = y0, lty = 2)
    points(xr, rep.int(y0, length(xr)))
    }
  ## return roots
  xr
  }
```

For cubic interpolation splines returned by `stats::splinefun` with methods `"fmm"`, `"natrual"`, `"periodic"` and `"hyman"`, the following function provides a stable numerical solution.

```
RootSpline3 <- function (f, y0 = 0, verbose = TRUE) {
  ## extract piecewise construction info
  info <- environment(f)$z
  n_pieces <- info$n - 1L
  x <- info$x; y <- info$y
  b <- info$b; c <- info$c; d <- info$d
  ## list of roots on each piece
  xr <- vector("list", n_pieces)
  ## loop through pieces
  i <- 1L
  while (i <= n_pieces) {
    ## complex roots
    croots <- polyroot(c(y[i] - y0, b[i], c[i], d[i]))
    ## real roots (be careful when testing 0 for floating point numbers)
    rroots <- Re(croots)[round(Im(croots), 10) == 0]
    ## the parametrization is for (x - x[i]), so need to shift the roots
    rroots <- rroots + x[i]
    ## real roots in (x[i], x[i + 1])
    xr[[i]] <- rroots[(rroots >= x[i]) & (rroots <= x[i + 1])]
    ## next piece
    i <- i + 1L
    }
  ## collapse list to atomic vector
  xr <- unlist(xr)
  ## make a plot?
  if (verbose) {
    curve(f, from = x[1], to = x[n_pieces + 1], xlab = "x", ylab = "f(x)")
    abline(h = y0, lty = 2)
    points(xr, rep.int(y0, length(xr)))
    }
  ## return roots
  xr
  }
```

It uses `polyroot` piecewise, first finding all roots on *complex* field, then retaining only *real* ones on the piecewise interval. This works because a cubic interpolation spline is just a number of piecewise cubic polynomials. My answer at [How to save and load spline interpolation functions in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51540182/4891738) has shown how to obtain piecewise polynomial coefficients, so using `polyroot` is straightforward.

Using the example data in the question, both `RootSpline1` and `RootSpline3` correctly identify all roots.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
RootSpline1(x, y, 2.85)
#[1] 3.495375 6.606465
RootSpline3(f3, 2.85)
#[1] 3.924512 6.435812 9.207171 9.886640
```

[image]

Comment: The `RootSpline3` function has been enhanced to function `solve` in my R package: `SplinesUtils`: https://github.com/ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils. Get it by `devtools::install_github("ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils")`.

Comment: Absolutely legendary answer

Answer (score 3):

Given data points and spline function as above, simply apply `findzeros()` from the *pracma* package.

```
library(pracma)
xs <- findzeros(function(x) f3(x) - 2.85,min(x), max(x))

xs  # [1] 3.924513 6.435812 9.207169 9.886618
points(xs, f3(xs))
```

Comment: `pracma::findzeros` and `rootSolve::uniroot.all` have the same logic: dividing the interval into many sub-interval and find roots on each interval then combine those results. For spline functions the knots naturally partition the function into pieces, avoiding any artificial subdivision. Also, the `solve` function from `SplineUtils` can solve the derivatives, too, essentially finding all extrema of a spline.

Comment: @李哲源  It appears your function `RootSpline3` does not find roots when the spline just touches the `y=y0` line (without crossing it). See e.g. `RootSpline3(f3, 5.40650874247)` which returns `numeric(0)` while `f3(5.10264982141)` is equal to this value (and gets found by `findzeros`). Of course, this example is artificial, but it can happen that a spline is touching `y0=2.0` and the inverse value is searched for.

Comment: Some round-off error has occurred and `base::polyroot` fails to return the root with good precision. Need some time to understand the behavior of `polyroot` to find a fix.