# How I use numerical methods to calculate roots in R

Tags: r, optimization, numerical-methods

A machine learning model predicted probability `p` using input `x`. It is unknown how model calculates the probability.

In the example below,

We have 100 `x`and `p` values.

Can someone please show an algorithm to find all values of x for which `p` is 0.5.

There are two challenges

1. I don't know the function `p = f(x)`. I don't wish to fit some smooth polynomial curves which will remove the noise. The noises are important.
2. `x` values are discrete. So, we need to interpolate to find the desired values of `x`.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,1.9,2.0, 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,3.0,3.1,3.2,3.3,3.4,3.5,3.6,3.7,3.8,3.9,4.0,4.1, 4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7,4.8,4.9,5.0,5.1,5.2,5.3,5.4,5.5,5.6,5.7,5.8,5.9,6.0,6.1,6.2, 6.3,6.4,6.5,6.6,6.7,6.8,6.9,7.0,7.1,7.2,7.3,7.4,7.5,7.6,7.7,7.8,7.9,8.0,8.1,8.2,8.3, 8.4,8.5,8.6,8.7,8.8,8.9,9.0,9.1,9.2,9.3,9.4,9.5,9.6,9.7,9.8,9.9, 10.0)
p <- c(0.69385203,0.67153592,0.64868391,0.72205029,0.64917218,0.66818861,0.55532616,0.58631660,0.65013198,0.53695673,0.57401464,0.57812980,0.39889101,0.41922821,0.44022287,0.48610191,0.34235438,0.30877592,0.20408235,0.17221558,0.23667792,0.29237938,0.10278049,0.20981142,0.08563396,0.12080935,0.03266140,0.12362265,0.11210208,0.08364931,0.04746024,0.14754152,0.09865584,0.16588175,0.16581508,0.14036209,0.20431540,0.19971309,0.23336415,0.12444293,0.14120138,0.21566896,0.18490258,0.34261082,0.38338941,0.41828079,0.34217964,0.38137610,0.41641546,0.58767796,0.45473784,0.60015956,0.63484702,0.55080768,0.60981219,0.71217369,0.60736818,0.78073246,0.68643671,0.79230105,0.76443958,0.74410139,0.63418201,0.64126278,0.63164615,0.68326471,0.68154362,0.75890922,0.72917978,0.55839943,0.55452549,0.69419777,0.64160572,0.63205751,0.60118916,0.40162340,0.38523375,0.39309260,0.47021037,0.33391614,0.22400555,0.20929558,0.20003229,0.15848124,0.11589228,0.13326047,0.11848593,0.17024106,0.11184393,0.12506915,0.07740497,0.02548386,0.07381765,0.02610759,0.13271803,0.07034573,0.02549706,0.02503864,0.11621910,0.08636754)


tbl <- tibble(x, p)


# plot for visualization
ggplot(data = tbl,
       aes(x = x,
           y = p)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(aspect.ratio = 0.4)
```

The figure below shows that there are five roots.

[image]

Comment: "The noises are important": this statement is hard to believe. And on the plot, I would only consider 3 significant roots.

Comment: That is true, practically there should be only three roots. But it is important to demonstrate that model suggested five roots.

Comment: I am using deeplearning models. Yes that's a good point. I am trying to explore the consequences of the rough fit.

Comment: "it is important to demonstrate that model suggested five roots": I don't believe for a second that these roots in a random signal are significant (but this is not my business).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is clearer than your previous one: [How I use numerical methods to calculate roots in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73087587/4891738).

> I don't know the function p = f(x)

So you don't have a `predict` function to calculate `p` for new `x` values. This is odd, though. Many statistical models have methods for `predict`. As BenBolker mentioned, the "obvious" solution is to use `uniroot` or more automated routines to find a or all roots, for the following template function:

```
function (x, model, p.target) predict(model, x) - p.target
```

But this does not work for you. You only have a set of `(x, p)` values that look noisy.

> I don't wish to fit some smooth polynomial curves which will remove the noise. The noises are important.

So we need to interpolate those `(x, p)` values for a function p = f(x).

> So, we need to interpolate to find the desired values of `x`.

Exactly. The question is what interpolation method to use.

> The figure below shows that there are five roots.

This line chart is actually a linear interpolation, consisting of piecewise line segments. To find where it crosses a horizontal line, you can use function `RootSpline1` defined in my Q & A back in 2018: [get x-value given y-value: general root finding for linear / non-linear interpolation function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52655742/4891738)

```
RootSpline1(x, p, 0.5)
#[1] 1.243590 4.948805 5.065953 5.131125 7.550705
```

[image: plot]

> Thank you very much. Please add the information of how to install the required package. That will help everyone.

This function is not in a package. But this is a good suggestion. I am now thinking of collecting all functions I wrote on Stack Overflow in a package.

The linked Q & A does mention an **R** package on GitHub: https://github.com/ZheyuanLi/SplinesUtils, but it focuses on splines of higher degree, like cubic interpolation spline, cubic smoothing spline and regression B-splines. Linear interpolation is not dealt with there. So for the moment, you need to grab function `RootSpline1` from my Stack Overflow answer.